# How to setup git on ubutu server?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-commit

I want to configure git on ubutu server and commit our source code using shell command.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do it directly from the IDE or do you mind doing it through the shell?

Comment: shell method also accepted but not want to commit one by one files

Answer (score 1):

Personally if you want to commit to a git repo using Ubuntu I would use the shell. 
You will have to go into the git repo directory by:

```
cd /this/is/my/path
```

After this command is completed IF you have git installed then commit if it is already connected to the repo 
E.g.

```
git commit -am "first commit"
```

If you would want to do it through the IDE you'll have to set up git to the IDE

Comment: Thanks,but I have a question there is no need to any setup into your local folder because as I know when you commit use push and get command and for this need the .git file into folder

Comment: What is the question mate?

Comment: and 
git commit -am "first commit" where I will config my git in which git repo code commit

Comment: Well how have you actually done it? Have you done a git clone of your link then used it in the IDE or are you making a new git repo?

Comment: :- sorry your answer is not helpful for me its not working correct command is 

 git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/{bitbuket name}/Repo
 git push -u origin master
  git commit "commit message"

Comment: Didn't know whether you were going to use SSH :) but congrats on getting the answer

Answer (score 0):

here explain how to direct commit code with Aptana but its hang system so use the shell command or other tool for commit code like **SmartGit**

http://nealbuerger.com/2013/11/aptana-eclipse-set-up-git-repository-github-bitbucket/